# The Mobile page preview of a a wordpress website page is different on elementor and Customize option. The changes for mobile affects desktop. Why?

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

The Mobile page preview of  a wordpress website page is different on elementor and Customize option. The changes for mobile affects Desktop preview. Why ?

I tried to do many things like hosting support but nothing worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.